# How to get the 1 month latest log from a log file using power shell

Tags: powershell

How to display the lastest 1 month line from a log file.

Ex.of the most recent line from my log is with this format. 
`"Mon Oct 14 11:16:29 2019 -- Loading Internal Cal"`.

I used power shell command,to get the latest line from the log file.

```
Get-Content \\teruflex063\tester\calibration.log -tail 1 -Wait |
    where {$_ -match "2019"}
```

I want my result to look like this

```
Sat Sept 14 11:16:29 2019 -- Loading Internal Cal
.
.
Mon Oct 14 11:16:29 2019 -- Loading Internal Cal
```

Comment: your `-Tail` parameter tells PoSh to give you ONLY the very last line. if you want all the lines starting one month before the last line, you will need to get all the lines that will be included in that range. that means either [A] load all the lines & filter for the desired date range, OR [B] know in advance the number of lines to `-Tail` to include your desired date range, OR [C] grab chunks of lines from the end until you reach the date range you want. ///// the 1st of those seems most direct ... [*grin*] .

Comment: I like -tail since it load the entire cal log from most recent. Do you have idea on getting the date from the entire string from the example?                            
Mon Oct 14 11:16:29 2019 -- Loading Internal Cal

Comment: since you seem to want the date parsed from the last line, not the last month of lines, i put the code for that in an answer. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

from you last comment, it appears you are actually asking how to parse the date from that last line of the file. [*grin*] if so, then this will do the job ...

```
$Line = 'Mon Oct 14 11:16:29 2019 -- Loading Internal Cal'
$TimeStamp = ($Line -split ' -- ')[0].Trim()

$DTInfo = [datetime]::ParseExact($TimeStamp, 'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy', $Null)

$DTInfo
```

output ...

```
2019 October 14, Monday 11:16:29 AM
```

note that my date format is set to a custom one, not the en-US default.

Comment: It worked! now that I have the latest date on this format, "2019 October 14, Monday 11:16:29 AM", I want this to be my reference and read my 36MB log file and filter only the most recent 1 month data. I hope to run or load it backwards up to  date not later than "2019 Sept 14, Sat 11:16:29 AM" so loading will be faster.

Comment: @RaymondCruzin - i don't know of any way to load from the end without repeatedly grabbing lines & testing them. [*blush*] do you have any rough idea how many lines you may need to load to go back a month?

Comment: Maybe 10,000 lines. what could you suggest?

Comment: i would look at the `StreamReader` stuff. it is apparently _quite_ fast. [*grin*] if you are comfy with c#, then do a search here for "read from end of file" for several ways to do it ... one of them uses `StreamReader`.

Comment: Do you also have a way to just filter log from specific datetime to latest? Since I now have a start date to start my filter. I could try to load from start of the line instead of the very last line.........................................................................................................................            PS C:\Users\raymond.cruzin> $latestdate
2019-10-14 05:37:50 Mon

PS C:\Users\raymond.cruzin> $lastmonth
2019-09-14 05:37:50 Sat

Comment: the `$DTInfo` variable holds a `datetime` object, not a date _string_. take a look at `$DTInfo | Get-Member` for some ideas ... one is to do something like `$TargetDate = $DTInfo.AddMonths(-1)` to get the date a month earlier. you can also do datetime math by literally subtracting two datetime objects.